# Insert only one time

Tags: oracle, insert

I want to make sure that when I execute my query, that it will fit only one time

```
INSERT INTO SERVICEPAYANT ( TYPE_FLUX, DELAI ) VALUES (160,'9999');
INSERT INTO SERVICEPAYANT ( TYPE_FLUX, DELAI ) VALUES (161,'9999');
INSERT INTO SERVICEPAYANT ( TYPE_FLUX, DELAI ) VALUES (162,'9999');
INSERT INTO SERVICEPAYANT ( TYPE_FLUX, DELAI ) VALUES (163,'9999');
```

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicate insertions then you (or someone else) MUST add constraints to the table. Constraints are enforced for all queries, not just those that bother to check for previous existence before inserting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO SERVICEPAYANT 
            (TYPE_FLUX, 
             DELAI) 
SELECT 161, 
       '9999' 
FROM   dual  
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   SERVICEPAYANT 
                   WHERE  TYPE_FLUX = 161 
                          AND DELAI = '9999')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how to manage it with several insert?

Comment: Create a proc and pass the param  TYPE_FLUX, DELAI in that param. Now use the query poste dby me in that proc and replace the values with parameteres in the query.

Comment: Note that this will not stop duplicate values being inserted if there is more than one concurrent session.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I have already told OP to use SP to insert records for full assurance that there will be no duplicate data.

Comment: @Romil - no. Implementing this insert within a stored procedure will do nothing to stop duplicate records being inserted.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, Stored procedures are reusable, not reentrant. This means that only one user at a time can execute a given copy of a procedure's. This means no simultaneous execution, no duplicate record insertion.

Comment: @Romil, you lost me there. Unless you serialise access to the procedure (e.g. by deliberately coding a call to DBMS_LOCK.request), many sessions can call the procedure at the same time.

Comment: You might want to read this for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i61063

Answer (score 1):

Can I take it that the combination of both columns is your natural key? If so, you need a uniquity constraint, this will depend on your database implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to mark the column `TYPE_FLUX` or `DELAI` as `UNIQUE KEY` if you already have a `PRIMARY KEY` on some other column in the Table. This will give you an error when you enter `161` in column `TYPE_FLUX` agin or an error when you enter `'9999'` in column `DELAI` again.

If you want the combination of the two columns to be unique then create a combined `UNIQUE KEY` this will never let `161 and '9999'` be entered in the table again **TOGETHER**

Comment: regrettably, I can not change the constraints on this table